# Mac OS 10.7 QGIS 1.8 Desktop Install Problem

Tags: qgis, installation

I've downloaded QGIS-1.8.0-2.dmg and the required GDAL Complete 1.9 framework package and GSL framework.  The frameworks are installed; however, when I try to start the installation of QGIS-1.8.0-2.dmg, I receive this warning: "...disk images couldn't be opened", reason: not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a corrupted download of QGIS-1.8.0-2.dmg. The Mac OS X ["disk images couldn't be opened" error](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3155874) is almost always due to an invalid .dmg file.

Try re-downloading it from [kyngchaos.com's qgis page](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). If you didn't get the supporting frameworks and QGIS-1.8.0-2 installer directly from kyngchaos.com or another trusted source listed at [QGIS.org's download page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download)... I suggest you not install whatever you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems doing much the same install but I installed the QGIS package BEFORE the GDAL and Frameworks packages.  You might find that changing the order of installation might help.

Comment: Hi Nigel. Hmmm, that shouldn't work. There is an `function pm_install_check` in the Distribution file of the installer package for QGIS.app that shouldn't allow it to be installed if any of the supporting frameworks are missing. Either the script's not working, or you possibly had a preexisting install of older frameworks. Installing the QGIS.app last, after the frameworks, is the correct order.

Comment: Thanks dakcarto. It may well be that the frameworks from a previous install were indeed there as I did do a complete second install of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue several times. Then I turned off my VPN, and it worked. Hope that helps.